# sending email to multiple accounts using php ews

Tags: php-ews

The below code is used for sending email using `jamesiarmes/php-ews`
 in my application

```
 $request = new \jamesiarmes\PhpEws\Request\CreateItemType();
  $request->MessageDisposition = "SendOnly";
  $request->SavedItemFolderId->DistinguishedFolderId->Id = "sentitems";
  $request->Items->Message->ItemClass = "IPM.Note";
  $request->Items->Message->Subject = "exchange new mail";
  $request->Items->Message->Body->BodyType = 'HTML';
  $request->Items->Message->Body->_ = "This is a test mail as a part of exchange settings set up ";
 $request->Items->Message->ToRecipients->Mailbox->EmailAddress = "rejith.rj@pitsolutions.com";
 $response = $this->app['ews']->CreateItem($request);
```

But the problem is I can add only one email address as recipient, how can I add multiple email addresses in `ToRecipients`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked out the [php-ews documentation](http://jamesarmes.com/php-ews/doc/0.1/examples/email-send.html). You can create an array with multiple recipients this way:

```
$toAddresses = array();

$toAddresses[0] = new EWSType_EmailAddressType();
$toAddresses[0]->EmailAddress = 'john.harris@domain.com';
$toAddresses[0]->Name = 'John Harris';

$toAddresses[1] = new EWSType_EmailAddressType();
$toAddresses[1]->EmailAddress = 'sara.smith@domain.com';
$toAddresses[1]->Name = 'Sara Smith';
```

And then add it to your object like this:

```
$request->Items->Message->ToRecipients = $toAddresses;
```

Try this and feedback me please.

Comment: Dear Andy, I tried what you have mentioned, still problem not solved

Comment: Glad to hear that, have fun coding! :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that your problem has not been solve yet?

Following works for me:

```
$toAddresses = array();
$toAddresses[0]="test@test.com";
$toAddresses[1]="test2@test.com";

$api = MailAPI::withUsernameAndPassword("server", "username", "password");

$message = new Type\MessageType();
$message->setBody('Some Text');
$message->setSubject('Test Subject');
$message->setToRecipients($toAddresses);
```